# Cryptographic Hash vs. MAC (or, why hash alone is insufficient)

Tags: authentication, cryptography, hash

There are already a couple of questions raised comparing Hash and MAC, but I searched and did not find answer to my question.

Usually we send "Encrypt(M, k) || MAC(M, K)" so that the receiver can check the message integrity and authentication.

But it seems that "Encrypt(M,k) || Hash(M)" works the same. Is this scheme for message authentication vulnerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that even naive Encrypt-and-MAC (i.e. `Encrypt(M, k) || MAC(M, K)`) have vulnerability. If the attacker knows a number of possible plaintext that the message could possibly contain, then they can figure out the content of a message by comparing with the MAC/hash of known plaintext. The Encrypt-and-Hash also suffers from the same vulnerability, and is a lot easier since the attacker can generate their own hashes by calculating the hash of similar texts rather than having to have to intercept past messages with identical content.

For example, if you know that Alice always sends Bob a message every 6AM one of three possible coffee choices: "Today's coffee is Cappuccino/Black/Moccacino", then if the hash of the message matches one of them, you would know Alice's choice of coffee.

With MAC, you'll need to match it with a previous known plaintext or an "oracle" (that can generate encrypted messages with your chosen plaintext). This is called the [chosen plaintext attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack).

Currently accepted best practice is to Encrypt-then-MAC (i.e. `Encrypt(M, k) || MAC(Encrypt(M, k), K)`).

So the question becomes, why not replace this with Encrypt-then-hash: `Encrypt(M, k) || Hash(Encrypt(M, k))` is obvious. Since anyone can calculate the hash of the encrypted part, this hash do not actually provide authentication.

Bonus: Another possible construction is MAC-then-Encrypt (i.e. `Encrypt(MAC(M, K), k)`), this is vulnerable to attacks that modified the encrypted text, which will likely produce garbage on the server and be rejected due to incorrect hash, but can still provide useful information to the attacker. One such attack is the [padding oracle attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack). Hash-then-Encrypt is vulnerable to the same attack.

I suggest reading on the topics of Authenticated encryption or Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data.

Comment: I agree that the Hash as an authentication tag leaks too much information compared to MAC. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand your example of why naive Encrypt-and-MAC is vulnerable. The attacker knows the hash of a given plaintext, but surely not the MAC? Isn't the whole point of MAC that it uses a key (i.e. K) that makes the output impossible to predict if you don't know K?

Answer (score 3):

Just as you added the *authentication* tag to your question, that is actually the answer to it.  The MAC involves a piece of information that should be known only to the parties that are communicating: the key.  When paired with encryption (as in your questions), MACs are used with symmetric encryption, therefore the key shall be the same and known only to the two parties communicating.

Contrary to a simple hash (which provides *integrity*) a MAC also provides *authentication*.

(In asymmetric encryption digital signatures provide these features.)

This is not extremely important when performing encryption since an attacker would need the decrypted message to generate the hash anyway.  The *authentication* part of the MAC is much more important in not encrypted communication.

Hell, assuming that `K` is key of a block cypher and `M` the plaintext then:

- `Encrypt(M, K) || MAC(M, K)`
- `Encrypt(M, K) || Hash(M || K)`

Are equivalent on high level meaning.  Since a cryptographic hash that receives a secret key as the input is a valid way of generating a MAC.

Comment: So do you mean that "Encrypt(M,k) || Hash(M)" indeed works the same?

Comment: MAC does not provide non-repudiation. The recipient of the message had to know the key to validate the MAC, and therefore the recipient would be able to forge a message with valid MAC.

Comment: @LieRyan - Very good point.  That was a brain fart when I was writing it, confused with digital signatures that I used in the next sentence.  Thanks.

Comment: @Infinite - I'll argue that yes, "Encrypt(M, K) || Hash(M)" is good enough for almost all cases where "Encrypt(M, K) || MAC(M, K)" can be used.  The single case that I can think of where they would be different is if `Encrypt()` and `Hash()` would be generated by procedures (e.g. processes) with access to different information (e.g. the process that computes `Hash()` does not know `K`).  In that case they're different because a broken hash algorithm would allow for a replay attack.  That's why it is wiser to use `Hash(M||K)` (i.e. a MAC).

Comment: @grochmal As I understand, `Hash(M)` doesn't know anything about `K` since `K` is not one of its args; that is, because these are mathematical (i.e. stateless) functions. Allowing some kind of hidden state makes these short function signatures useless without looking at a real function definition. (Consider passing the state in explicitly: `Hash(S(K,M))` where `S` is some kind of state (value) based on `K` and `M`. `Hash` definitely has the needed state now, because it's passed in, and with `Encrypt(S(K,M))` we get shared state. You've already given one definition for `S`--- `S(K,M) = M || K`)